# How do you verify Selenium Webdriver results?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have to automate some test cases in Selenium Webdriver (Java/Eclipse).

I have to verify the correct layout of many URLs/templates, and also the correct behavior of interactive components.

I can do the steps so far with no problems. The verification is the part I'm having issues with.

I was thinking of taking screenshots of each step. Then after all the test cases are ran, I would check the screenshots manually to verify the layout and behavior was as expected. Also I would put Asserts to verify some things in some steps.

1) What's the best way for analyzing results? Screenshots and Asserts are ok? are enough?
2) For multiple test cases running in parallel, what would you recommend?
3) To be able to execute the test cases in the background, so they don't interfiere with my computer as I keep working, what would you recommend? I need the test cases to be run in many browsers (IE11, Chrome, Firefox and also these browsers in Mobile/Tablet resolution).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Depending on your requirements, screenshots and assertions may be sufficient to verify your testing results but this isn't really something that can be answered properly on stack overflow - you should instead confirm with the stakeholder for the application you're testing what *they* want.
2. For running multiple tests in parallel, I would recommend investigating [Selenium-Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp).
3. To run your tests in an unobtrusive way on your computer (i.e. not displaying in the foreground) perhaps you could set up one or more virtual machines as nodes on a Selenium-Grid?

Answer (score 1):

1.) the ideal asserts are 1 to 3 per test case, anything more than that means that you need to split your tests. Normally, I don't rely on automation for checking UIs. I do that manually, it helps me to check both ui and ux at the same time.

3). You can always toggle your main window to "always in top" so new browser instances will not pop up every time.